# How to iterate records spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro

I have a variable "myrdd" that is an avro file with 10 records loaded through hadoopfile.

When I do

```
myrdd.first_1.datum.getName()
```

I can get the name. Problem is, I have 10 records in "myrdd". When I do:

```
myrdd.map(x => {println(x._1.datum.getName())})
```

it does not work and prints out a weird object a single time. How can I iterate over all records?

Comment: Question needs example. It should cover both the avro data and the problematic output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a log from a session using `spark-shell` with a similar scenario.

Given

```
scala> persons
res8: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: int]

scala> persons.first
res7: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [Justin,19]
```

Your issue looks like

```
scala> persons.map(t => println(t))
res4: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Unit] = MapPartitionsRDD[10]
```

so `map` just returns another RDD (the function is not applied immediately, the function is applied "lazily" when you really iterate over the result).

So when you materialize (using `collect()`) you get a "normal" collection:

```
scala> persons.collect()
res11: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([Justin,19])
```

over which which you can `map`. Note that in this case you have a side-effect in the closure passed to `map` (the `println`), the result of `println` is `Unit`):

```
scala> persons.collect().map(t => println(t))
[Justin,19]
res5: Array[Unit] = Array(())
```

Same result if `collect` is applied at the end:

```
scala> persons.map(t => println(t)).collect()
[Justin,19]
res19: Array[Unit] = Array(())
```

But if you just want to print the rows, you can simplify it to using `foreach`:

```
scala> persons.foreach(t => println(t))
[Justin,19]
```

As @RohanAletty has pointed out in a comment, this works for a local Spark job. If the job runs in a cluster, `collect` is required as well:

```
persons.collect().foreach(t => println(t))
```

---

Notes

- The same behaviour can be observed in the `Iterator` class.
- The output of the session above has been reordered

---

**Update**

As for filtering: The location of `collect` is "bad", if you apply filters after `collect` which can be applied before.

For example these expressions give the same result:

```
scala> persons.filter("age > 20").collect().foreach(println)
[Michael,29]
[Andy,30]

scala> persons.collect().filter(r => r.getInt(1) >= 20).foreach(println)
[Michael,29]
[Andy,30]
```

but the 2nd case is worse, because that filter could have been applied before `collect`.

The same applies to any type of aggregation as well.

Comment: Just a small note: if this is running on a cluster, you would need to use `take()` or `collect()` on the RDD before calling `foreach(println)`. This is because, data must be brought back to the driver since the spark context runs there. (For a local spark progam, your answer works fine.)

Comment: If I had a million records, I heard collect is bad because all that data is sent to your machine... Is there a way to make it so that say, I could "prefilter" out all the names that are "Justin" and age 18/19 before doing the foreach(println)? Basically, if I have a 5 node cluster, I want to "divy" up the prefiltering work amongst all the machines before looping through the remaining records I want to output.

Comment: @Rolando Please have a look at the updated answer - I have added an example with a filter on "both sides" of `collect`.

Comment: @RohanAletty Thanks for the hint; I have updated the answer