# Assign new value to var in loop

Tags: scala

Don´t have access to var in loop. Why? thanks.

```
   var grupo = "A"
   for (a <- dataframe) {
        grupo = "B"
    }
    println(grupo) //Print A
```

Edit!

dataframe filterP show like this:

```
|   CODIGO|LISTA|NUMERO|OPCION|NUMERO|OP|VALOR|
+---------+-----+------+------+------+--+-----+
|110111001|    P|  0000|     A|  0000| 1|    1|
|110111001|    P|  0000|     A|  0000| 1|    1|
|110111001|    P|  0000|     A|  0000| 1|    2|
|110111001|    P|  0000|     A|  0000| 1|    3|
|110111001|    P|  0000|     A|  0000| 1|    1|
|110111001|    P|  0000|     B|  0000| 1|    2|
```

Code:

```
var grupo = List(filterP.first()(3).toString())
   var grupo_tmp = grupo(0)
   println("first group:" + grupo(0))
   for (a <- filterP) {
       if(grupo_tmp != a(3).toString()){
         println(grupo_tmp + "|" + a(3).toString())
         grupo = a(3).toString() :: grupo
         grupo_tmp = a(3).toString()
       }
    }
    println(grupo_tmp)
    println("Grupos de lista "+grupo.length)
    for(i <- 0 to grupo.length-1){ 
      println("grupo: "+ grupo(i))
    }
```

This print:

```
   first group:A
   A|B
   A
   Grupos de lista 1
   grupo: A
```

I don`t see where is the problem..

Comment: If `dataframe` is  some distributed context such as spark, always remeber that code may executed on another machine. So never use var, use other api instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering how your `for` loop is working without you collecting the `filterP` `dataframe`. `for` loop is just `transformation` and `println` should not have executed without an `action` on the `dataframe`.

`Dataframes` are partitioned by dafault and I am guessing is that your `dataframe` is partitioned and you are getting only partial output.

collecting `dataframe` to the `driver` should solve the issue

```
var grupo = List(filterP.first()(3).toString())
var grupo_tmp = grupo(0)
println("first group:" + grupo(0))
for (a <- filterP.collect) { //collect the dataframe to the driver
  if(grupo_tmp != a(3).toString()){
    println(grupo_tmp + "|" + a(3).toString())
    grupo = a(3).toString() :: grupo
    grupo_tmp = a(3).toString()
  }
}
println(grupo_tmp)
println("Grupos de lista "+grupo.length)
for(i <- 0 to grupo.length-1){
  println("grupo: "+ grupo(i))
}
```

I get the output as

```
first group:A
A|B
B
Grupos de lista 2
grupo: B
grupo: A
```

Comment: It's work! Thank you very much!! I'm starting with scala.

Comment: Thats great news :) happy for you

Answer (score 2):

It definitely has access to `var` inside loop.

- Maybe you have a separate variable inside a loop named `grupo` or
- maybe you loop is not meeting the conditions at all, meaning `dataframe` is empty.
- try printing `a` inside your loop to debug.

see the example,

```
scala> var grupo = "A"
grupo: String = A

scala> for (a <- Array("MUTATE-1", "MUTATE-2")) { grupo = a }

scala> grupo
res6: String = MUTATE-2
```

Comment: Your example works. I do not understand what may be happening. 
I'm going to edit the question with the original code. 
Thank you very much

Comment: @J.M.P.R. can you post the value of `dataframe`? Trying having `println(a)` inside loop as well

Comment: so `dataframe` is need to be mapped to collected - see example https://stackoverflow.com/a/33031744/432903